# Issue with /usr/include/pci/pci.h missing on CentOS Linux, make of C++ applications with g++ fails

Tags: centos, rhel, c++, pci, g++

I am working on a large C/C++ development project, we are using Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6 for our development network, and also using g++ and gcc and also gmake.

Management directed us to install a virtual machine with Oracle VirtualBox with Red Hat CentOS Linux 6.10 so we can continue to do software development when our RHEL network is down for upgrades and/or maintenance. CentOS Linux and RHEL are supposed to be identical so our C/C++ applications should be able to be made and ran on either OS.

However, I encounter a strange issue when trying to make one of our applications on the CentOS Linux VM. it appears to not be able to find the following file which is included in a cpp file that is a composite part of the application.

```
/usr/include/pci/pci.h
```

The include statement is:

```
#include <pci/pci.h>
```

Doing a make the following error is generated:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpci
```

Doing a review of the C++ application, it actually has includes for two different pci.h files, like the following:

```
#include <pci/pci.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
```

On our RHEL, where the error does not occur, the files for both of these includes are present, as well as some composite .h files:

```
/usr/include/pci/pci.h
/usr/include/linux/pci.h
```

On our CentOS Linux VM, the following folder and files are not present, but are present on our RHEL:

```
/usr/include/pci/pci.h
/usr/include/pci/config.h
/usr/include/pci/header.h
/usr/include/pci/types.h
```

The folder /usr/include/pci is not present on our CentOS Linux VM, Also, trying to install pciutils gives a message "already installed". The file /usr/include/linux/pci.h is on our CentOS Linux VM, and strangely, the lspci command also works on our CentOS Linux.

So trying various Google and Bing searches on this issue did not find much info. I think this is not actually a bug in the CentOS Linux, but is actually a configuration issue where the pci is left out on our CentOS Linux VM. Not exactly sure how to correct the issue. I think it might be a simple issue to resolve.

Comment: What is the output of `yum whatprovides "/usr/include/pci/pci.h"` on your CentOS system?

Comment: Hello, someone said I should install pciutils-devel, and that corrected the error when I installed it from an rpm, to answer your question the output is "pciutils-devel-3.1.10-4.el6.x86_64 : Linux PCI development library"

Comment: And that is what the output of `yum whatprovides "/usr/include/pci/pci.h"` would have told you.

Comment: Just to let you know, your development platform, RHEL6, is ending active support later this year (November, 2020). You might want to consider something newer if this project has a timeline past then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `pciutils-devel`.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed, YUM could not find it in any of the mirrors though, so I downloaded and installed the RPM file from centos.org, now the error is not occurring.